# Round decimal places seaborn heatmap labels

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I have a heat map that gets its labels automatically, however some of them are long decimals (I don't understand why because the values I used for the heatmap have 3 decimals, for example 0.009 appears as a long decimal), I would like to round all labels to 4 decimals places. Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
table1 = df.pivot('ToxinK','Khill','Fraction') #Putting information from the dataframe into a pivot table
sns.heatmap(table1,cmap='Purples',norm=LogNorm())
```

[image]

I have tried a solution that I found on [seaborn too long numeric labels](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1005), however is not working for me, I don't know why
Here is the attempt:

```
majorFormatter = FormatStrFormatter('%0.4f')
ax1=sns.heatmap(table1,cmap='Purples',norm=LogNorm())
ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)
```

[image]

Any advice or piece of information on how to solve this problem would be incredibly useful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `tabel1 = df.pivot('ToxinK','Khill','Fraction').round(4)`.

Comment: Yeah, using df.ToxinK=df.ToxinK.round(4) did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To format the annotations, enter the argument `fmt='.4f'` for 4 decimal places.
Taking your first code as example:

```py
sns.heatmap(table1, cmap='Purples', fmt='.4f')
```